# What is the number of $5$-card hands in a $52$-card deck that contain two pairs(i.e. two pairs from different ranks,and a fifth card of a third rank)?

Tags: combinatorics

A standard deck of cards contains $52$ cards divided into four suits:
the red suits, hearts and diamonds, and the black suits, clubs and spades. Each suit, in turn, is divided in 13 ordered ranks: ace through 10 followed by the face cards jack, queen, and king. The ace can act as either the lowest or highest card in the ranking.

> What is the number of $5$-card hands in a $52$-card deck that contain two pairs (i.e., two pairs from different ranks, and a fifth card of a third rank)?

Answer: $\binom {13}{2}{\binom 42}^2 \binom {44}{1}$

Why is $\binom {13}{2}$ a factor in the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you choose the two different ranks (one for each pair) so you get :

$$\begin{pmatrix}13\\2\end{pmatrix}\text{ choices.} $$

For each one of these choices you must choose two different suits for the first rank :

$$\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}\text{ choices.} $$

you must choose two different suits for the second rank :

$$\begin{pmatrix}4\\2\end{pmatrix}\text{ choices.} $$

And you must choose a last card which is among the remaining ranks :

$$(13-2)\times 4=44\text{ choices. } $$

Comment: Is it the more general version of this rule: Consider $2-$lists for which there are $n$ choices for the first element and for each choice of the first element there are m choices for the second element. Then the number of such lists is nm. For example one possible list is (Jack, Spade, 10). Is that correct?